# TensorFlow output shape with Shape Function

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am writing a custom TensorFlow Op in C++ and CUDA as per the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) and am confused about the setting of the ops output shape. I wish to be able to provide the desired output dimensions as an attribute and use this attribute to set the shape with `SetShapeFn`

My op code is very much a straight adaptation of the example linked above, however, I am not sure how to use the provided attribute in this way.

```
REGISTER_OP("GaussianProcess")
.Attr("output_dim: int") //This is the desired output dimension.
.Input("data_points: float32")
.Input("query_point: float32")
.Input("alpha: float32")
.Input("hyp: float32")
.Output("shape_descriptor: float32")
.SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      /*
       Use attribute 'output_dim' here.
      */
});
```

For the above Op registration, how would one access the `output_dim` attribute in the lambda passed to `SetShapeFn`?

I need to be able to pass it to a call like so:

```
c->set_output(0, output_dim);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InferenceContext` allows getting attributes via the `GetAttr` method. So you can get `output_dim` like this:

```
int output_dim;
c->GetAttr("output_dim", &output_dim);
```

Hope that helps!